# Sendkeys to first field of page sometimes fails

Tags: java, selenium

I'm testing an userdatapage with **Selenium Webdriver/Java 7/ Firefox**.
I have a set of 13 different testdata stored in a table in Excel.
The first test is about missing the name of the user, the second test is about an incorrect value for the name of the user, the third is about in correct password value and so on. 
For the userdatapage I'm  using a pageobject instantiated with the `pagefactory` model of `Selenium`..

From time to time, but not very often, the name field, the first field on the page, is not filled. What I'm doing is first `click`, then `clear` and finally `send keys` to the field.

I can add some delay to the code but what I'm not understanding is why in this case there isn't thrown an element not found exception. Is this because I'm using the `PageFactory` concept. Can somebody explain this to me?

This is the HTML of the first inputfield:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="input-group">
        <div class="input-group-addon">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>
            <span class="asterisk glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="input-group-input">
           <input type="text"  class="form-control" name="inputName"     title="Volledige naam inclusief voorletters of voornaam" placeholder="Voorletters/Voornaam Achternaam"data-bind="value:name"/>
             <span class="help-block" id="naamMessage">    </span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And here is the `Java` code to fill the field:

```
public void setUserData(String naam, String password, String passwordRepeat, String land, String straat,
        String postcode, String stad, String telefoonnr, String akkoord) {

    setInputNameTextBox(naam);
    setInputPasswordTextBox(password);
    setInputPasswordRepeatTextBox(passwordRepeat);
    setInputCountryTextBox(land);
    setInputStreetTextBox(straat);
    setInputZipCodeTextBox(postcode);
    setInputCityTextBox(stad);
    setInputPhoneTextBox(telefoonnr);
    if (akkoord != "") {
        clickInputApprove();
    }

}

public void setInputNameTextBox(String naam) {
    inputName.click();
    inputName.clear();
    inputName.sendKeys(naam);
}
```

Comment: Provide `HTML` for input fields and code you tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use AjaxElementLocatorFactory in your POM class and check if it throws error in this case.

Comment: I added this AjaxElementLocatorFactory to the POM class an until now there was no failure during testing. What I'm not sure about is, does it make sense to add this AjaxElementFactory, this is not a dynamic webpage.

Comment: AjaxElementLocatorFactory is a lazy load concept in Page Factory pattern to identify WebElements only when they are used in any operation i.e. a timeOut for a WebElement can be assigned to the Object page class with the help of AjaxElementLocatorFactory.it is basically behave same as implicit wait. You can use this concept to implement implicit wait in better and efficient way. Whether your page is dynamic or not.

Comment: Thank you for your clear explanation of the AjaxElementLocatorFactory concept.